# Cannot install python pillow due to gcc-4.2

Tags: python, gcc4, python-imaging-library

I have tried so many things to get this going. I have been through as many of the numerous threads on problems with gcc-4.2 but it's still not working. Does anyone have any sage advice to nip this one in the bud?

I'm on Snow Leopard OSX 6.8.

Thanks

```
~/code: pip install pillow
     Downloading/unpacking pillow
     Downloading Pillow-2.3.0.zip (2.4Mb): 2.4Mb downloaded
     Running setup.py egg_info for package pillow

Installing collected packages: pillow
  Running setup.py install for pillow

    --- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks
    building 'PIL._imaging' extension
    gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_imaging.o
    gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c decode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/decode.o
    In file included from decode.c:416:
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:10:20: error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:13:18: error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from decode.c:416:
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:30: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘tdata_t’
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘ttag_t’
    In file included from decode.c:416:
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:10:20: error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:13:18: error: tiff.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from decode.c:416:
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:30: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘tdata_t’
    /Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘ttag_t’
    lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/6H/6H1XlbmGH2KSrJyf0XI4Ck+++TI/-Tmp-//ccbGKQc0.out
    error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/6H/6H1XlbmGH2KSrJyf0XI4Ck+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-efu6j4-record/install-record.txt:
    running install

running build

running build_py

creating build

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7

creating build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_binary.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/_util.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ArgImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BdfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ContainerIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/CurImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ExifTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FliImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GdImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GifImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpGradientFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/Image.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageChops.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageCms.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageColor.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageDraw2.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageEnhance.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFileIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFilter.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageFont.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageGrab.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageMode.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageOps.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePalette.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImagePath.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageQt.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageSequence.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageShow.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageStat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTk.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageTransform.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImageWin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/JpegPresets.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MicImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/MspImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/OleFileIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PaletteFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcfFontFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PngImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/PSDraw.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/SunImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TarIO.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/tests.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/TiffTags.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WalImageFile.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

copying PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/PIL

running egg_info

writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'

writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

running build_ext

--- using frameworks at /System/Library/Frameworks

building 'PIL._imaging' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/libImaging

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/_imaging.o

gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -DHAVE_LIBJPEG -DHAVE_LIBZ -DHAVE_LIBTIFF -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tcl.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Headers -I/opt/local/include/freetype2 -I/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/X11/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c decode.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-intel-2.7/decode.o

In file included from decode.c:416:

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:10:20: error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:13:18: error: tiff.h: No such file or directory

In file included from decode.c:416:

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:30: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘tdata_t’

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘ttag_t’

In file included from decode.c:416:

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:10:20: error: tiffio.h: No such file or directory

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:13:18: error: tiff.h: No such file or directory

In file included from decode.c:416:

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:30: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘tdata_t’

/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/libImaging/TiffDecode.h:43: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘ttag_t’

lipo: can't figure out the architecture type of: /var/folders/6H/6H1XlbmGH2KSrJyf0XI4Ck+++TI/-Tmp-//ccbGKQc0.out

error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/methuselah/code/build/pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/6H/6H1XlbmGH2KSrJyf0XI4Ck+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-efu6j4-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /Users/methuselah/.pip/pip.log
~/code:
```

Comment: You need libtiff development headers. No idea about the procedure on a MAC.

Answer (score 2):

My best advice would be to use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org) (or alternatively [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install all the dependencies needed, otherwise it's a real pain in the neck to chase them all down manually. I prefer MacPorts, but others don't, so your mileage may vary. To show how easy it is, on my system I'd just run:

```
sudo port install py27-Pillow
```

and it'd all automagically be configured and installed. Of course, this does require installing the MacPorts version of Python as well, but you should be able to move most if not all of your `site-packages` over if the versions match up. There are great docs on the website, check them out.